# Dar un salto de linea con Javascript en HTML (sin <br>)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, salto-de-linea

Estoy utilizando Angular.
A través del `Data Binding`, quiero mostrar un string que creo con typescript.
El problema que me surge con esto es que quiero realizar un salto de linea, justamente con "\n" como en otros lenguajes.

Entiendo que typescript y javascript es practicamente lo mismo y por eso no debería influir el "\n".

Este es mi código:

```
  getWayPay(wayPayParam: WayPay): string {
    if (wayPayParam.wayPayName <= 0) {
      return '--';
    } else {
      const WAY_PAY: any = wayPay; //Inserted constant
      let daysString = wayPayParam.days == 1 ? ' día - ' : ' días - ';
      return  WAY_PAY[wayPayParam.wayPayName] + "\n" + wayPayParam.days + daysString + wayPayParam.percentage + '%';;
    }
  }
```

El código, funciona bien, muestra los datos que yo quiero. La duda me surge con "\n" como antes mencioné, no se imprime con salto de linea.

Código HTML:

```
<span class="value">{{getWayPay(wayPay)}}</span>
```

En la página se muestra así:

(Bueno, en este momento no me deja cargar la imagen, ni bien pueda la subo pero por ejemplo aparece:)

Contra entrega 3 días - 97.5%

(Un texto de corrido)

Probé cambiando:

- por las `'comillas simples'`.
- por las `"comillas dobles"`
- cambiando en HTML  `<span>` por `<p>`
- y por ultimo: cambiando `'\n` por `<br>` (pero en este caso se imprime con eso xD)

Comment: Hola, puedes probar con innerHTML, pero te recomiendo tener cuidado por insert de scripts <div [innerHTML]="elContendio"></div>

Comment: Si es para mostrar en el navegador, entonces debes usar `<br>`, no hay otra forma. Bueno, sí, pero no con buenas prácticas. Los navegadores ignoran espacios múltiples, tabuladores y saltos de línea al mostrar textos.